# Spring Boot : PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer is not loading system properties

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound=true,value={"classpath:application.properties","classpath:util-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"})
@ComponentScan("com.jmarts")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilderconfigure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    } 
}
```

- I'm making use of spring profiles and based on active profile, a the correct environment specific file is loaded: utils-local.properties, utils-dev.properties, etc...
- When profile is set through application.properties (spring), e.g. spring.profiles.active=local all works great, correct file (utils-local.properties)is loaded.
- Providing profile through -D (gradle bootRun -Dspring.profiles.active=local) doesn't load profile. I was able to verify that the system properties is passed (print systemProperties)

I assume spring boot will register a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer if none is configured.

Answer (score 0):

spring boot officially supports [profile-specific properties using the naming convention application-{profile}.properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-arguments).
so you can remove "classpath:util-${spring.profiles.active}.properties" and add application-local.properties, application-dev.properties and so on in the classpath.